# Syntax error in INSERT INTO statement. asp.net

Tags: asp.net, syntax, insert

can i ask about this, im getting syntax error in INSERT INTO statement. whenever i press ctrl+f5. is there anything missing with my code?

```
Protected Sub btnEnter_Click(sender As Object, e As System.EventArgs) Handles btnEnter.Click

    Dim CID As Integer = CInt(lblCno.Text)
    Dim tRentID As String = txtRentID.Text
    Dim pList As String = ProductList.Text
    Dim tDate As Date = lblDue.Text
    Dim amount As Integer = CInt(txtAmount.Text)
    Try
        Dim dbconn1, dbcomm1, dbex1, sql1
        dbconn1 = New OleDbConnection("Provider=Microsoft.Jet.OLEDB.4.0;" & "Data Source=" & Server.MapPath("~/App_Data/aspDatabase.mdb"))
        dbconn1.open()
        sql1 = "Insert into order VALUES ( " & "'" & tRentID & "'" & "," & "'" & tDate & "'" & "," & "'" & amount & "'" & "," & "'" & CID & "'" & "," & pList & ")"
        dbcomm1 = New OleDbCommand(sql1, dbconn1)
        dbex1 = dbcomm1.executenonquery
        dbconn1.Close()
    Catch ex As Exception
        lblOut.Text = ex.Message
    End Try
End Sub
End Class
```

Comment: I would strongly encourage you to use parameterized queries. This insert statement is a SQL injection disaster waiting to happen

Comment: @TimothyHenrySusanto You can make your statement easier to read by reducing, for example, `& "'" & "," & "'" &` to `& "','" &`, but parameterized queries are the best option.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`ORDER` is a reserved keyword. Surround it in square brackets [order] (or back-ticks, depending on the database you are using). It is square brackets for Access.